# Image inside <li> hiding numbers?

Tags: html, css

```
<ol>
   <li><img src="someimage" class="pic"> text</li>
   <li>some </li>
</ol>
```

And style:

```
.pic {float:left;}
```

Basically the first element doesn't show `1.`  the count starts from the second `<li>` with `2.`

If if remove the float:left on the image then the number 1. shows again. Any thoughts?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jHS2S/
Screenshot: http://i45.tinypic.com/34t7eaq.png

Comment: what is the size(dimension) of your image?

Comment: It's not clear from the question if you want to hide the number or to show it. Please elaborate.

Comment: You need to provide more of your css and if possible either recreate the issue in a http://jsfiddle.net or a link to the site. As the behaviour you've described should not happen based on the current html and css. As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/jHS2S/

Comment: I've just looked at my fiddle again and I can see that it's only Chrome that incorrectly displays it. Can you confirm your issue is only Chrome related? Also is there any reason you need to float the image left? Doesn't it already show in the right place without?

Comment: @tw16: IE8 gives almost the same result: http://i45.tinypic.com/34t7eaq.png Of course if i remove float:left it looks good. But i would like to understand why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Is your list-style-position set on the list?  If you are using `list-style-position:inside;` the number is inside of  the li container and will be covered by float:left's.  Try `list-style-position:outside;`

You'll probably also want to add a `clear:left` to your li class if your image is much taller than your line height.

Comment: is it covering up the first item numeral in the list, or numerals for subsequent items?

Answer (score 0):

Let the image size is 24x24 then use

```
<ol>
   <li style="min-height:24px;"><img src="someimage" class="pic"> text</li>
   <li style="min-height:24px;">some </li>
</ol>
```

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/jHS2S/1/

Comment: The numbers of list item are not aligned on that jsfiddle

Comment: but its perfect of ff/ie/safari :-(